# System Generator: How to make a buffer implementation

Tags: xilinx-system-generator, buffer

I would like to make a buffer in system generator to use it with a FFT block.
I want to charge 16 values to a FFT block from another system I´ve designed and I need a temporary memory system. Could anyone tell me what xilinx blocks I have to use to get a buffer?
Thank you so much.

Comment: @perterstone, someone has already had a question about it, could you possible give a link to what the system generator is?

Answer (score 1):

Is System Generator a graphic tool? (I use different FPGA vendors so not sure, but most have an equivalent tool where you place blocks, or create new ones from HDL and use them) **edit** - just checked and it seems to be such a tool for creating DSP designs.

If I understand correctly then:
If it's a small buffer then you can probably just do it in some "glue" HDL with registers, linking the two System Generator generated blocks. Otherwise use a RAM/FIFO block of some sort that will be available in System Generator.

The System Generator [user manual](http://www.xilinx.com/support/sw_manuals/sysgen_user.pdf) (e.g. page 15-18) discusses memories and implementing as part of a larger design using an HDL "wrapper".

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about to use RAM or FIFO blocks, I´m waiting for an advice from a experienced user. But may be it´s no neccesary to design a buffer. I think the FFT block should be contain a interna register system as a buffer.

Comment: I am trying to find out. I hope anyone of you could give me an usefull advice about this question.

Comment: Yes, System Generator is a xilinx program that is used with Matlab - Simulink